# Where is the authorization information exactly stored?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#step_1_enable_the_api_name
Under the notes section of Google Calendar API it says that:

"Authorization information is stored on the file system, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization."

Comment: All the authorization information you get from google is stored on to "Downloads" of your file system. Once the information is stored, it avoids users to prompt for consent screen for authorization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials file's location is specified in the CREDENTIALS_PATH variable.
use the expandHomeDirectory function to get the exact location.

`$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
echo $credentialsPath`

Mine is is located on: C:\Users\MyUsername\.credentials\calendar-php-quickstart.json

The reason I asked this is that I am having an error saying

> Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client".....

I deleted the file to become authenticated again.