# Gmail API: replace client_secret.json file to change account

Tags: python, gmail-api

I want to change my python script to to send emails from another gmail account. Following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) I have created a new `client_secret.json` and replaced the old file. However, the script still sends the email using the previous account.

I remember the first time I setup the `client_secret` a year ago, a browser opened up and asked for authorization, so I think there should be some cached data somewhere which still points to the old account. I am not sure how I can clear the cached data and force the code to use the new account.

In the same documentation linked above it says

> Authorization information is stored on the file system, so subsequent
>   executions will not prompt for authorization.

but doesn't mention where in the file system it's stored.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in this SO thread: 
[Where is the authorization information exactly stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312432/where-is-the-authorization-information-exactly-stored)

Although the above SO question is related to calendar, but it was the same for gmail and it worked for me.